# Sending a file using TCPClient and NetworkStream in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient

I've been trying to send a file from a client to a server application using the TCPClient class in C#. Before I send the actual data, I send some additional information like the exact file size and the file name, so the server application knows how much there is to read. The funny thing is everything was fine when I tested it on 127.0.0.1 - as soon as I replaced the IP address with the actual one, the server could only read about 1,5 KByte of the data that was sent. It still gets the filename and the file size, but theres no way it's retrieving the actual data.

For testing purposes, I replaced the image I was going to send with a simple string and the transmission went alright, so I suppose there is a problem with sending and receiving the data chunks, but I'm not getting any exceptions on the client side either.

Anyone got an idea? Cheers!

Edit:

Thanks so far, this is what I have got codewise. For the client:

```
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.xx.xx");
        int port = 3003;
        int bufferSize = 1024;

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream netStream;

        // Connect to server
        try
        {
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        netStream = client.GetStream();

        // Read bytes from image
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Dan\\Desktop\\asdf.jpg");

        // Build the package
        byte[] dataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
        byte[] package = new byte[4 + data.Length];
        dataLength.CopyTo(package, 0);
        data.CopyTo(package, 4);

        // Send to server
        int bytesSent = 0;
        int bytesLeft = package.Length;

        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {

            int nextPacketSize = (bytesLeft > bufferSize) ? bufferSize : bytesLeft;

            netStream.Write(package, bytesSent, nextPacketSize);
            bytesSent += nextPacketSize;
            bytesLeft -= nextPacketSize;

        }

        // Clean up
        netStream.Close();
        client.Close();
```

And the server:

```
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(3003);
        TcpClient client;
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        NetworkStream netStream;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int allBytesRead = 0;

        // Start listening
        listen.Start();

        // Accept client
        client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
        netStream = client.GetStream();

        // Read length of incoming data
        byte[] length = new byte[4];
        bytesRead = netStream.Read(length, 0, 4);
        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(length,0);

        // Read the data
        int bytesLeft = dataLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];

        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {

            int nextPacketSize = (bytesLeft > bufferSize) ? bufferSize : bytesLeft;

            bytesRead = netStream.Read(data, allBytesRead, nextPacketSize);
            allBytesRead += bytesRead;
            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;

        }

        // Save image to desktop
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Dan\\Desktop\\tcpimage.jpg", data);

        // Clean up
        netStream.Close();
        client.Close();
```

Comment: Please post the code - otherwise we could go down all kinds of blind alleys.

Comment: I'm afraid we need to see some code. Testing locally and remotely can yield very different results (for one, testing locally is kinda like direct so you wont meet the common gotcha's that quickly)

Comment: Did you actually read in a loop, or did you just call `Read` once? You can also use `BinaryReader.ReadToEnd`

Comment: Thanks so far, I've added the code in the original post. Cheers

Comment: And what happens at NetworkStream.Read when you've received 1500 bytes? Does it block? Does it return zero?

Comment: I checked it again, it always reads 1456 Bytes and blocks then.

Comment: [1500 byte packet size] - [20 bytes ip header] - [24 bytes tcp header] = 1456 bytes of data. How much is the total size of the data? Is the second packet expected to be less 1500 bytes? Have you tried calling Flush at the sender? Have you tried disable the nagle algorithm?

Comment: The total size of the data is about 150kb, so the next packet is supposed to have 1024 bytes aswell. I already tried calling Flush and setting NoDelay to true - no success so far

Comment: So, the second call to NetworkStream.Read has allBytesRead>0 (from the first call) and a valid nextPacketSize (1024?) but never returns?

Comment: There is a bug in your code in that it assumes that the 4 byte length prefix will be read entirely. That does not necessarily hold.

Comment: You can replace the entire sending loop with one call to Write. Write out the entire buffer. (This is not related to the problem you are having.) You seem to have some misunderstanding regarding "packets". You want to split everything into 1024 byte chunks. That does not serve any purpose. Read as much as there is space in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

About 1.5 KiB sounds like 1500 bytes, "the largest allowed by Ethernet at the network layer". This is the [maximum transmission unit (mtu)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) forcing your network stack to split your file into several small packets.

You need to call the [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) in a loop to read every packet arrived. There's example code of this at MSDN.

Combine this with the default behavior of .NET; consolidating smaller packets to reduce the amount of packets sent, and you'll also see this behavior when sending smaller packets. This can be controlled with [ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.usenaglealgorithm.aspx) or by using smaller scoped socket options.

Comment: ServicePointManager is only used with Http connections.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Ok, don't know what I'm doing here, but</strike> in case of anyone uses this as referrence.

I got rid of unnecessary copying and done a *very* important improvement. Your way to calc `nextPacketSize` is not complete, since there could be less data, than 1024 avaliable, and you'll get extra nulls in between these chunks (I had a lot of headache with that, now so happy to figure out)

I made them as function, needed for several files, so here's code:

## client

*this one is almost the same*

```
public void sendData(byte[] data, NetworkStream stream)
{
    int bufferSize = 1024;

    byte[] dataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);

    stream.Write(dataLength, 0, 4);

    int bytesSent = 0;
    int bytesLeft = data.Length;

    while (bytesLeft > 0)
    {
        int curDataSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, bytesLeft);

        stream.Write(data, bytesSent, curDataSize);

        bytesSent += curDataSize;
        bytesLeft -= curDataSize;
    }
}
```

## server

```
public byte[] getData(TcpClient client)
{
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[4];
    int bytes = stream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, 4);
    int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeBytes, 0);

    int bytesLeft = dataLength;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];

    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (bytesLeft > 0)
    {
        int curDataSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, bytesLeft);
        if (client.Available < curDataSize)
            curDataSize = client.Available; //This saved me

        bytes = stream.Read(data, bytesRead, curDataSize);

        bytesRead += curDataSize;
        bytesLeft -= curDataSize;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a simple explanation on how to send the buffer size and chunks of data. This really cuts it down to the important lines.

Comment: Why `int bytesSent = 0;`? 4 bytes are sent with `stream.Write(dataLength, 0, 4);`, so `bytesSent` should be equals 4?

Comment: @Kre4 good point, I guess this is also true for reading. I don't really work with C# anymore, can't say much here. Anyway, now I wonder why it worked so well when I used it? Aren't I just overwrite the whole `data` on `stream.Read`?

Comment: @Kre4 ok, I've done some research. `bytesSent` doesn't count the amount of data sent to stream in total, but the offset for the original data. As per documentation, second argument is the offset for the `buffer`, which is first argument. Same goes for reading, offset regulates where to write data in first argument. The only stream related argument is third -- amount of bytes to exchange with stream.

Answer (score 0):

I used some of your code for a test networking project I'm working on.  I tweaked a couple things to fit the requirements of my project, but one alteration I needed to make to the original code is to add a "-4" to the line that was setting the bytesLeft variable.  After that the code worked.  My test file is 52KB & was transmitted successfully.

```
      // Read the data
    int bytesLeft = dataLength-4;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
```